# Python find the minimum using for loops?

Tags: python, loops, minimum

I don't know how to make python "scan" through the list for a candidate and then go back to the loop again to find another candidate for the min.

```
    candidate = 0
    maximum = 0
    a = [12, 10, 50, 100, 24]
    for i in len(s):
        for j in range(len(s)):
```

Comment: Why are you using two loops? Finding the minimum is O(n) time for an unsorted array.

Comment: What is `s` in `len(s)`?

Comment: Also, whatever `s` is, `len(s)` is almost certainly a number, so `for i in len(s)` is going to be a `TypeError`. You got the loop over a range right in the next line, what's different about this one? (Although really, `for i in a: for j in a:` is a lot simpler, no mucking about with indices at all.)

Comment: If this is an assignment, maybe post the full text of the assignment rather than your summary of it. Obviously you don't fully understand the assignment or you wouldn't be asking this question, but hopefully people here would.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the builtin [`min`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function to do this

```
a = [12, 10, 50, 100, 24]
print min(a)
```

If you really want to use loop,

```
minimum = a[0]
for number in a:
    if minimum > number:
       minimum = number
print minimum
```

You can use [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function to find the maximum in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to handle this for any sort of iterable, including generators:

```
def my_minimum(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    minimum = iterable.next()
    for i in iterable:
        if i < minimum:
            minimum = i
    return minimum

>>> a = [12, 10, 50, 100, 24]
>>> my_minimum(a)
10
```

Which takes generators:

```
>>> b = xrange(20)
>>> my_minimum(b)
0
```

However, as the others mentioned, Python has its own built-in `min` function, so I hope this question is purely academic.

```
>>> min(a)
10
```

Which also takes generators:

```
>>> b = xrange(20)
>>> min(b)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `min` and `max` functions, like this:

```
>>> min([12,10,50,100,24])
10
>>> max([12,10,50,100,24])
100
```