# Find min and max value of any function over an interval

Tags: python, function, max, intervals, min

I know there are some similar questions, but all of them want/or get the answere using numpy.

I want to find the max and min value of a string, e.g. ("Sin(x**2)") over the interval: x [0,10].

I was given this hint by my teacher; *Specically, we try with 1001 different values from 1 to 10 and implement the evaluation function using eval, with values
x {(i/100, i[0,1000] }.
This can realised by using a for loop where i in range(0,1001) and using increments x = i / 100.0.*

Note: I cannot use numpy.

Comment: Hint basically outlines all your program. Assign x to i/100.0, eval(expression), update maximum and minimum values if the result of eval is larger / smaller than the current maximum / minimum. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359883/python-find-the-minimum-using-for-loops/21359894#21359894

Comment: FWIW, you're assuming a certain amount of well-behavedness in the function if you thing that it can be reasonably well be described in a discretized state like this...  e.g. I can define a function which is 0 everywhere except at the value `pi` where it has a value of 30015.7.  Unless you happen to sample at `pi`, you'd never know that discontinuity was there and you wouldn't get the max.

Comment: Why don't you use a `for` loop where `i in range(0,1001):` and then within that loop let `x = i / 100.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
def compute_min_and_max(expression):
    min_value, max_value = float("inf"), float("-inf")
    for x in range(1001):
        res = eval(expression, None, {"sin": math.sin, "x": x/100.0})
        if min_value > res: min_value = res
        if max_value < res: max_value = res
    return(min_value, max_value)

print(compute_min_and_max("sin(x ** 2)"))
```

**Output**

```
(-0.9999939135141118, 0.9999999062300194)
```

Comment: First: You're just implementing the OP's homework for him, with no explanation? Second: Your function fails for monotonically decreasing input. Minimal test case: `compute_min_and_max("-x")`

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks man :) I managed to fix the `-x` part with your help.

Comment: You can drop the `ast` import

Comment: @gnibbler Thanks :) I forgot to remove that.